# Why use Redis with PostgreSQL, why not just one of them?

Tags: django, postgresql, redis

I have seen all over the web that people are configuring their PostgreSQL along side Redis. My question is, why would someone want to use in-memory storage system like Redis, when they have already configured permanent storage system like PostgreSQL.

I get that Redis works with RAM and that it is much faster, but is that the only reason?

Answer (score 1):

There might be lot of combinations why people use that stack, but this is **not** necessary for **all** sites. That might be used, for example, for counting most visited pages, or Redis is good brocker for using with async tasks, like Celery. But yep, on my oponion the only reason to use it - is speed.